# How can I turn on/off my AWS EC2 Scheduler with Lambda/DynamoDB twice a day?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, scheduler

I want to set a schedule for my EC2 to turn on twice a day at two specific times - at 12:00AM and at 12:00PM - and turn off after 30mins (at 12:30PM and 00:30AM).

I created one EC2 Scheduler/Table (tagname: Schedule) and I then setup two schedules in the config file (refresh-1 and refresh-2), which include the two periods/hours.

When I add the "key" and "value" fields to my "Manage Tasks" page in EC2, I get an error message saying that I can only specific a unique tag key.

[image]

Does this mean that I need two separate EC2 Schedulers/Tables in order to turn on/off my EC2 at two different times? For instance:

- an EC2 Scheduler/Table with key: Schedule and value: refresh-1
- another EC2 Scheduler/Table with key: Schedule-2 and value: refresh-2

What's the simplest solution to set this up, trying to leverage just one EC2 Scheduler/Table?

NB: I'd like to use Lambda/DynamoDB, not other solutions preferably.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you are seeing is because you cannot have two EC2 tags with the same key.  So you may only have a single `Schedule` tag on each EC2 instance.

[After reviewing the EC2 Instance Scheduler documentation](https://s3.amazonaws.com/solutions-reference/aws-instance-scheduler/latest/instance-scheduler.pdf), you should create two periods instead of creating two schedules.  One period for 12:00am-12:30am and another for 12:00pm to 12:30pm.  Then create one schedule that references both periods.

Using the CLI it would be something like:

```
$ scheduler-cli create-period --name noon30 --begintime 12:00 --endtime 12:30 --stack Scheduler

$ scheduler-cli create-period --name midnight30 --begintime 00:00 --endtime 00:30 --stack Scheduler

$ scheduler-cli create-schedule --name my-refresh --periods
noon30,midnight30 --timezone Europe/London --stack Scheduler
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. This made me realise that I could add an extra period to the schedule, by simply adding a new string. Therefore, I created two periods, and then added both to my schedule under the "periods" section. This is what I included: {"refresh-am","refresh-pm"}

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the AWS Instance Scheduler, you might be interested in the [Simple EC2 Stopinator in Lambda - DEV Community](https://dev.to/aws/simple-ec2-stopinator-in-lambda-5goj) that I created. It uses a single Lambda function and an IAM Role, nothing else.

It can specify a duration after which the instance should be terminated (good for sandbox testing), and it can schedule instance stoppage.

It should be fairly easy to modify to set a Start Time too.